# how can I flip from camera to screen recording

Tags: youtube, tutorial

I just get my new canon 70d camera. I want to use it for recording online tutorial and publish it in YouTube. how can I flip from camera to screen recording and vise verse while recording? are there some programs for doing that?

Comment: Are you trying to stream live or just record it while switching live so that you can avoid doing post production on it?  Is there anyone else who can handle switching for you on another system or does it need to be on the same system?  Does it need to be free/cheap or can other production hardware be involved?  What kind of quality are you looking for and what is your budget?  There are a bunch of different ways this can be done, but without more detail, I can't give you the best one for your situation.

Comment: @AJHenderson Ok, I need to record the video, no one to switch the camera, free/cheep solution will be perfect and i can't get any new hardware since i am living in Gaza-Palestine, it was sufferance to get the camera from out!, HD for youtube. please tell me if you have any other questions.. and thanks

Comment: Can you edit after the fact or does it have to be live? There is software that can record the video switching like open broadcast software, but it is mostly for streaming and the ui might be visible. The quality would also be lower.

Comment: @AJHenderson yes i can edit, it's not live

Answer (score 2):

You have two main options I can see, first one is to take a look at [Open Broadcaster Software Project](https://obsproject.com/).  This project is free and open source and is targeted at individuals trying to stream primarily, but it does have good support for both a video capture device and a screen capture.  I believe it is possible to configure a shortcut key for swapping sources and it does support local recording.

For this option, you will also need a way to capture the video from the camera.  You can either use a webcam hack to pull the preview video from EOS Utility using some third party drivers (Covered in more detail [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8953/use-canon-t3i-as-a-hd-webcam)) or you can purchase an HDMI input device, such as a Matrox MXO2 or BlackMagic Intensity (not free or even particularly cheap, but necessary if you want to make use of the HDMI out of your camera.

Alternately, you can just use standard screen recording software and record the video independently.  You can then edit them together after the fact.  To avoid sync problems, you can start by showing the camera the screen and opening and closing a window to sync to later.  This is the cheapest option as it can be done without any additional investment using entirely free tools.  It is also the highest quality option as non-real time encoding and hardware assisted encoding (such as on the camera) does a far higher quality job than software based real time encoding.  It also allows you to be the most selective about when you switch sources and preserves feeds of both sources in case you want to make changes later on.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of (does not mean its not out there), this would be very easy to do in Post production and since you have to pull the video of the camera card to upload it anyway just drop it in in post and keep the camera audio playing over it.

Comment: I won't down vote since you included that there might be, but just to let you know there are a fair number of ways to do this general thing (assuming he doesn't mean doing it solely with the camera, but rather recording from the computer).  I need to get some more details from the OP to tell which one is most relevant, but I should be able to put together an answer once I hear back.  If he actually means from the camera, then you are quite right that it is impossible as the camera doesn't have a way to feed in the screen capture.

Comment: Of course there is a way to do this with a video mixer but he was asking if there was a program for it, I have never seen one but Im sure they are out there. However if there is no one to operate it that would pose a problem. I felt like he was looking for a one button solution or a remote control solution that he could discreetly operate while on cameral. Shy of hiding a mixer under the table I do not know of anything. An A/B box would cause drop out in the switch but could be used.

Comment: see my answer for more details on how it can be done.  There is an entire class of streaming software designed specifically to do this kind of thing.  Even on the higher end, there are PC based video switches that could be controlled by shortcut keys while running something.  It's not particularly easy, or possibly even advisable, to run it yourself while presenting, but there are lots of means of being able to do it.